# Error asset path when using Proxy with sub-directory

Tags: playframework-2.0

I use Apache Proxy in the front of Play!.
In order to reuse my SSL certificate, 
the apache config is like this:

```
    <Location /balancer-manager>
            SetHandler balancer-manager
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
    </Location>
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:9997
    BalancerMember http://localhost:9998 status=+H
    </Proxy>
    <Proxy *>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow From All
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
    ProxyPass /play/ balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse /play http://localhost:9997/    
    ProxyPassReverse /play http://localhost:9998/
```

It seems ok at first, but i found that the asset path is not as expected.
The right path should like this `http://domain/play/jquery.js`
,but play! return like this `http://domain/jquery.js`,
therefore, Apache cannot resolve the url when user fetch the resources,
any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: And how do you use it in the template?

Comment: @biesior I don't modify my template, I think the relative path for templates should be unchanged, right?

Answer (score 0):

Play don't know anything about your Apache config - it still considers, that it still operates in the root folder of the domain. The cleanest approach you can use is (IMHO) using subdomain `http://play.domain.tld` instead of nested folder `http://domain.tld/play` otherwise you will need to reflect the `play` segment of the url in your routes.

Comment: Because I have to reuse my SSL certificate(single domain restricted), so it's not allowed me to using subdomain, what i am confused is the actions remain ok in this config but the resources not, why?